# Remove lens distortion from images captured by an wide angle (180) camera

Tags: image, opencv, opengl, image-processing, gimp

I have some images captured from an wide angle appx. (180 degree) camera.
I am using opencv 2.4.8 which gives some details about camera matrix n distortion matrix.

```
MatK = [537.43775285, 0, 327.61133999], [0, 536.95118778, 248.89561998], [0, 0, 1]
MatD = [-0.29741743, 0.14930169, 0, 0, 0]
```

And this info I have used further to remove the distortion.
But the result is not as expected. 
I have attached some input images of chess board which i have used to calibrate.
Or Is there any other tools or library by which it can be removed.

input images

[image: testImg1]

[image: testImg2]
[image: testImg3]
[image: testImg4]

**from a Normal Camera or even captured by my smart phone**
[image: without Distortion]
[image: without Distortion]
[image: without Distortion]

Comment: is that pattern really planar? the distortion looks very very strange. or did you use very bad mirror (e.g. coated light bulb) to get the wide-angle image?

Comment: Micka, its a COP CG180 Camera 180 degree Wide Angle lens and not the mirror.

Comment: Yes It is planer, check out some other images of the same board from other camera, now any idea about the same ?

Comment: looks like the lens is crap...

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer to the question, but something about the "discussion" of distortion and planarness.

In reality you have some straight lines on a pattern:

[image]

With (nearly any) lens you'll get some kind of distortion so that those straight lines aren't straight anymore after projection to your image. This effect is much stronger for wide angle lenses. You could expect something like this (for wide angle stronger but similar):

[image]

But the images you provided look more like this, which can be because of your pattern wasnt really planar on the ground, or because the lens has some additional "hills" on your lens.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Micka, Its right. distorted image really looks horrible I have tried opencv and ffmpeg also but images are not being corrected. As you are saying might Its lens internal problem also with distortion.

Comment: Hi @Micka Can software remove all distortion from a 180-degree lens? In other words, if the goal is to optimize for distortion-free images, would a stereo configuration with two 100-degree lenses and two sensors (overlapped to provide 180-deg coverage) be better than a single sensor with a 180-deg lens?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the calibration process is to tell OpenCV what a straight line looks like under distortion. A chess board is used to present a number of straight lines that are easy for OpenCV to detect. In your image, these lines are simply not straight. I'm moderately sure that OpenCV also needs square boxes.

So, use a real chess board pattern. Print it out, glue it to a piece of wood or hard plastic or whatever. But make sure it's a regular chessboard pattern on a level plane.

Comment: Dear Andreas, its a regular chess board pattern, but after capturing from wide angle camera it looks like as shown in images, And these are actual images i have captured from wide camera.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't believe that. The pattern may be regular, but it's not planar. On the bottom row of the pattern, look at the third black box from the left. This one is always in a wavy pattern, indicating that it is lifted off the surface the pattern rests on. It is like this in every image, making it unlikely that any irregularities in the camera lens are responsible.

Comment: @Javed At this point I'm under the impression that you don't know what the words "planar" or "level surface" mean, is that possible?

Comment: Andreas, Dear question is not like either you believe or not but if you know about lens distortion then you should atleast think all these image have been distorted. 
I have uploaded some other images of the same board from a normal camera, That looks fine or in your terms planer. But While the same is captured from the wide angle camera which has lens distortion then images looks non planer and distorted,
Also what what you & me understand by planer or surface leve keep it away, I really want to know if there is any way to fix these images.

Comment: Any suggestion or idea about that ?

Comment: I guess the lens is very very bad... not sure whether any standard undistortion methods will work there. Never seen such a distortion yet. Normally I would assume that distortion leads to some curvature in straight lines, but not in such continuing curvature changes of those lines... but Im not THAT experienced with distortion so I might be very wrong. maybe have a look at papers who cite this one: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00267247/PDF/distcalib.pdf

Comment: @Javed Sorry, I didn't mean it like "You're a liar!" or anything. Didn't mean to offend. The new pictures are clearly planar. It's just that to me it looks like the other pictures were taken before you taped down the pattern. If that is not the case, then the distortion of the camera is not just radial distortion, and I don't think OpenCV can help you.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, yes I do agree, it seems like its a mix distortion of radial and tangential and more complicated, its because if the ultra wide angle.

Comment: and not single radial

Comment: Thanks Micka, also i found this but still not getting it corrected http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lenscorrection/  for SQURE case

Comment: @Javed Crazy stuff. I'd really like to see a video of that 180 camera.

Comment: @Andreas, I have captured a video also.

Comment: @Javed Did you post a link somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The most common method (used by the Oculus Rift Runtime for example) draws a fine enough textured grid for which the texture coordinates or the grid node positions are chosen to compensate the distortion. To obtain the grid normally one fits a polynomial or a spline to some reference picture. For example the checkerboard in your camera is a common calibration target.

Comment: Can software remove all distortion from a 180-degree lens? In other words, if the goal is to optimize for distortion-free images, would a stereo configuration with two 100-degree lenses and two sensors (overlapped to provide 180-deg coverage) be better than a single sensor with a 180-deg lens?

Comment: @Crashalot: It depends on the distortion. In case that two distinct points in the world are imaged onto the same point in image the mapping is no longer bijective and can not be reversed. But *every* bijective mapping always can be reversed (that's right in the definition) and all real world optical lenses are bijective (in fact this property led to the introduction of the term "lens" into computer science: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_transformation#Vocabulary).

Comment: @Crashalot: Regarding if using multiple cameras can be beneficial: That really boils down to what kind of lens you're using and the sensor resolutions you're working with. Technically nothing forbids creating a lens that optically implements a Mercator projection (I have no idea how such a beast would look like); with enough computational power and the right combination of glasses this could be made very high quality (and expensive), but would easily outperform a multi-sensor-with-cheap-lenses configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! OK, to narrow the question: could a smartphone do the kind of processing that would allow a single lens/sensor (180-deg) to produce distortion-free images?

Comment: @Crashalot: Technically yes. And in practice, too, if the image resolution to be processed does not exceed the computational capabilities. Current generation smartphones easily are able to process FullHD sensor data in realtime using their GPUs.

Comment: Thanks! So what resolution would be too high? If you had to operate on a 1280x720 video (30 FPS) shot with a 180-deg lens, could a smartphone remove all distortion, even at the edges?

Comment: @Crashalot: That really depends on the hardware you have available. Performance gains between mobile device generations are significant. But as a general rule of thumb you can assume that a smartphone's GPU/CPU combination is beefy enough to process at least the resolution of the devices display at video framerates in realtime. And yes, you can remove all the *distortions*. But lenses produce also abberations (picture gets more blurry toward the edges) and these are much harder to get rid of; it's kind of possible but requires a specific optical setup.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing! Didn't realize there was a difference between distortions and aberrations. Tried finding your email, but couldn't find a definitive source. Is mail @ your-name.net the right one? Would you mind receiving an email?

Comment: @Crashalot: Yes, but it's heavily filtered. Here's a one-time address for you to use, that bypasses the filters: hah3Xiek8zagie9m@datenwolf.net

Comment: Thanks! Just sent an email.